# How to choose a fridge to convert to a kegerator

Tags: corny-keg, kegerator, gas, refrigerator

I'm going to be building a kegerator pretty soon and I'm pretty sure that I am going to buy a new fridge. Now, I have 1 corny keg but in the future, I would like 4 kegs hooked up, my wife also would like a chest freezer for storage. I think I can fit 2 kegs with gas in an under the counter fridge, so I'd need 2 and also this chest freezer. I was looking in the store today at refrigerators and I have found a fridge/freezer that I think I can satisfy everyone with! I can fit 4 kegs in the top and enough room for gas and a few bottles of ale. And the wife can have the bottom section for storage. This way will save me about £100.

This is the refrigerator I am thinking of getting: http://www.currys.co.uk/gbuk/household-appliances/refrigeration/fridge-freezers/indesit-biaa12p-uk-fridge-freezer-white-10023597-pdt.html

I have a few questions about this idea:

1. My beer lines will be a little longer, probably 2 meters, will this
   matter and importantly will it effect the beer?
2. Can I store the gas bottle outside of the fridge? Or does the
   CO2 have to be chilled also?
3. Can I cut my hole in the side of a fridge?

The benefits to having this style is cost saving and also it will take up less space (although not a massive issue)

Thanks

Comment: I have a kegerator that accommodates four cornies. It started its life as a freezer. If you find that a freezer fits the dimensions you need, you should be able to use it. The thermostats are the same on fridges and freezers, but they have a course-adjustment screw that sets the temperature. If you remove the knob for the thermostat, you should see a small hole that you can fit a screwdriver in to adjust it and turn a freezer into a fridge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. No, length is not a problem. Just coil your beerline and tape it together so that it is not a mess whenever you open the door.
2. CO2 should be outside the fridge.
3. Yes, you can drill through the side, but the door is usually the safest. When drilling through the side, avoid the 5cm around the sides as there are cooling tubes running there. An even better idea would be to talk to a person who repairs those fridges and ask them where it is safe to drill.

Comment: Thanks Atron. I was actually going to try and remove the side to actually locate the cooling lines but I'll see if I can find a repairman.

Comment: If you can take off the panels (and put them back) then that would probably be a better idea. I was unsure how to remove mine and the repairman was there to fix the compressor.... so I just asked.